# Team Foundation Server Troubles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am getting in a right mess with TFS 2012 Express and could use some help.

I currently develop using VS2010 and am trying to evaluate TFS 2012 Express. I installed TFS 2012 without any problems, and managed to get VS 2010 connecting to it fine. But when I come to create a new project I get some permissions error that Im not allowed to create a project.

This seems to be a recognised problem as outlined [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/tfsadmin/thread/da192608-964b-4652-b3a2-da55b8ddf2aa)

This thread suggests that to create a project I need to use another program to create the project. Does anyone have any experience of using vs2010 with TFS 2012 and if so how the heck did you manage to create a project :)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see as accepted answer in the link that you provided:

> Unfortunately you can't create TFS Team project on TFS 11 Beta with
>   Visual Studio 2010, so you will need to install and use Visual Studio
>   11 Beta.

When I started to use VS2008 with TFS2010 I had a similar problem. I fix it by installing a patch to VS2008 that allowed it to connect to TFS2010. Probably soon a patch will appear for VS2010 to connect to TFS2012..

**Possible solutions**

- Until the moment Microsoft create a patch you can install Team Explorer 2012 or VS2012 Beta (that includes Team Explorer 2012), create project and try to connect to existing project from VS2010.
- You can try TFS sidekicks to see if they have a version to connect to TFS2012 and create a project. Check http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tfsidekicks/archive/2010/01/03/team-foundation-sidekicks-for-2010-available.aspx and http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm

Comment: I tried downloading the program linked in that thread but got a number of errors and the program wouldnt start up. Im wondering if thats because Its designed for the 11 Beta and I actually have 2012 rc?

Comment: Which program are you talking about? Visual Studio 11 Beta?

Comment: I tried downloading team explorer for visual studio 11 beta as detailed here - http://berxpert.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/connect-vs2010-to-tfs-11-express/ but got a number of errors. Trying team explorer for 2012 now

Comment: Probably you are right. Old version. Try Team Explorer 2012 or vs2012beta (that contains Team Explorer)

Comment: You need to to use the same version of VS as TFS in order to create a team project.  In the case of TFS 2012, you need to use the same public release for each (beta with beta or RC with RC).  There error message is unfortunately not helpful.

Comment: Just to say I managed to create a new project using the 2012 Team Explorer RC

Comment: Congrats :)
If you think my answer was ok, please mark it as accepted answer. If not, you could always write your own answer to your question.